# Implementing a Custom Cocoa Event Tracking Loop

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm working on a custom cross platform UI library that needs a synchronous "ShowPopup" method that shows a popup, runs an event loop until it's finished and automatically cancels when clicking outside the popup or pressing escape.  Keyboard, mouse and scroll wheel events need to be dispatched to the popup but other events (paint, draw, timers etc...) need to be dispatched to their regular targets while the loop runs.

Edit: for clarification, by popup, I mean this kind of menu style popup window, not an alert/dialog etc...

[image: Cantabile Popup]

On Windows I've implemented this fairly simply by calling GetMessage/DispatchMessage and filtering and dispatching messages as appropriate.  Works fine.

I've much less experience with Cocoa/OS X however and finding the whole event loop/dispatch paradigm a bit confusing. I've seen the following article which explains how to implement a mouse tracking loop which is very similar to what I need:

http://stpeterandpaul.ca/tiger/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/chapter_5_section_4.html

but...  there's some things about this that concern me.

1. The linked article states:  "the application’s main thread is unable to process any other requests during an event-tracking loop and timers might not fire".  Might not?  Why not, when not, how to make sure they do?
2. The docs for [nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsapplication/1428485-nexteventmatchingmask?language=objc) states "events that do not match one of the specified event types are left in the queue.".  That seems a little odd.  Does this mean that if an event loop only asks for mouse events then any pressed keys will be processed once the loop finishes?  That'd be weird.
3. Is it possible to peek at a message in the event queue without removing it.  eg: the Windows version of my library uses this to close the popup when it's clicked outside, but leaves the click event in the queue so that clicking outside the popup on a another button doesn't require a second click.
4. I've read and re-read about run loop modes but still don't really get it.  A good explanation of what these are for would be great.
5. Are there any other good examples of implementing an event loop for a popup.  Even better would be pseudo-code for what the built in NSApplication run loop does.

Another way of putting all this... what's the Cocoa equivalent of Windows' `PeekMessage(..., PM_REMOVE)`, `PeekMessage(..., PM_NOREMOVE)` and `DispatchMessage()`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Synchronous methods that interact with the user or spin the event loop are fiction. They blatantly lie to the user, and then come bugs because code that was never meant to be reentered - is. I'd highly suggest not having any synchronous event loop spinning methods at all. None. Nobody is supposed to program that way in this century and decade anymore.

Comment: When a UI element changes state - i.e. a popup is dismissed, an asynchronous notification is issued to interested parties from within the event loop/dispatcher. If the application is anything but trivial, you'll want to formally describe its behavior in a (e.g. UML/SCXML) state machine driven by those events, otherwise you can consume them directly. Reentering the event loop is not portable - i.e. on different platforms, different reentrant events will issue from the sub-loop, and it promulgates the fiction that leads directly to spaghetti code. UI is not synchronous. Never was.

Comment: @KubaOber  Thanks - uploaded the image.  As for spinning synchronous event loop - that's exactly what the Apple documentation describes so I don't think it's "fiction".  Besides I got it working perfectly in the end using tips from Ken Thomases answer.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly is a "popup" as you're using the term? That term means different things in different GUI APIs. Is it just a modal dialog window?

---

**Update for edits to question:**

It seems you just want to implement a custom menu. Apple provides a sample project, [CustomMenus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html), which illustrates that technique. It's a companion to one of the WWDC 2010 session videos, [Session 145, "Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications"](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_145__key_event_handling_in_cocoa_applications.mov).

---

Depending on exactly what you need to achieve, you might want to use an `NSAlert`. Alternatively, you can use a custom window and just run it modally using the `-runModalForWindow:` method of `NSApplication`.

To meet your requirement of ending the modal session when the user clicks outside of the window, you could use a local event monitor. There's even an example of just such functionality in the (modern, current) Cocoa Event Handling Guide: [Monitoring Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html).

All of that said, here are (hopefully no longer relevant) answers to your specific questions:

> 1. The linked article states:  "the application’s main thread is unable to process any other requests during an event-tracking loop and
>      timers might not fire".  Might not?  Why not, when not, how to make
>      sure they do?

Because timers are scheduled in a particular run loop mode or set of modes. See the answer to question 4, below. You would typically use the event-tracking mode when running an event-tracking loop, so timers which are not scheduled in that mode will not run.

You could use the default mode for your event-tracking loop, but it really isn't a good idea. It might cause unexpected re-entrancy.

Assuming your pop-up is similar to a modal window, you should probably use `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`.

> 2. The docs for [nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsapplication/1428485-nexteventmatchingmask?language=objc)
>      states "events that do not match one of the specified event types are
>      left in the queue.".  That seems a little odd.  Does this mean that if
>      an event loop only asks for mouse events then any pressed keys will be
>      processed once the loop finishes?  That'd be weird.

Yes, that's what it means. It's up to you to prevent that weird outcome. If you were to read a version of the Cocoa Event Handling Guide from this decade, you'd find there's [a section on how to deal with this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW19). ;-P

> 3. Is it possible to peek at a message in the event queue without removing it.  eg: the Windows version of my library uses this to close
>      the popup when it's clicked outside, but leaves the click event in the
>      queue so that clicking outside the popup on a another button doesn't
>      require a second click.

Yes. Did you notice the "dequeue:" parameter of `nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:`? If you pass `NO` for that, then the event is left in the queue.

> 4. I've read and re-read about run loop modes but still don't really get it.  A good explanation of what these are for would be great.

It's hard to know what to tell you without knowing what you're confused about and how the [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) failed you.

Are you familiar with handling multiple asynchronous communication channels using a loop around `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`, or `kevent()`? It's kind of like that, but a bit more automated. Not only do you build a data structure which lists the input sources you want to monitor and what specific events on those input sources you're interested in, but each input source also has a callback associated with it. Running the run loop is like calling one of the above functions to wait for input but also, when input arrives, calling the callback associated with the source to handle that input. You can run a single turn of that loop, run it until a specific time, or even run it indefinitely.

With run loops, the input sources can be organized into sets. The sets are called "modes" and identified by name (i.e. a string). When you run a run loop, you specify which set of input sources it should monitor by specifying which mode it should run in. The other input sources are still known to the run loop, but just ignored temporarily.

The `-nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` method is, more or less, running the thread's run loop internally. In addition to whatever input sources were already present in the run loop, it temporarily adds an input source to monitor events from the windowing system, including mouse and key events.

> 5. Are there any other good examples of implementing an event loop for a popup.  Even better would be pseudo-code for what the built in
>      NSApplication run loop does.

There's old Apple sample code, which is actually their implementation of GLUT. It provides [a subclass of `NSApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/glut/Listings/GLUTApplication_m.html) and overrides the `-run` method. When you strip away some stuff that's only relevant for application start-up or GLUT, it's pretty simple. It's just a loop around `-nextEventMatchingMask:...` and `-sendEvent:`.

Comment: Hi Ken,  thanks for the detailed answer.  For clarification I've edited the original post to include a screen shot of the kind of popup I mean - basically a small popup window like a menu - not a dialog window.  I think I'm starting to understand how all this hangs together and will probably just implement by own run loop.  Thanks again

Comment: See my edit near the top for sample code and video explanation regarding implementing custom pop-up-menu-style windows.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  Very useful.